# Position spinner in the middle of another element (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that it should be simple, but could not do this for an hour or more.

I have a canvas which is of varying size so I want to position spinner always on top of canvas and in the center of it. Tried something like this:

```
    $rootScope.centerSpinner = function() {
        var spinner = $('.md-spinner');
        var canvas = $('.canvas-container');

        spinner.css({
            'top'  : (canvas.outerHeight() / 2) - (spinner.outerHeight(true) / 2),
            'left' : (canvas.outerWidth() / 2) - (spinner.outerWidth(true) / 2)
        });


    }
```

Did not work.

Answer (score 0):

It was easier than I thought:

```
   $rootScope.centerSpinner = function() {
        var spinner = $('#spinner');
        var left = $('#canvas').offset().left + $('#canvas').width()/2;
        var top = $('#canvas').offset().top + $('#canvas').height()/2;

        $('#spinner').css({
            "position" : "absolute",
            "left"     : left,
            "top"      : top
        });
    }
```